# How to change background color of MaterialButton through styles.xml

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I am trying to change the background color and text color of a material button-through style.
However, I see no change in IDE and as well as on phone.
Here is a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

The button next to cancel misbehaves, after checking in tons of attributes I fail to change background color.

Here is my XML:

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_login_skip"
                style="@style/myMaterialButton.Unboxed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/btn_login_login" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_login_login"
                style="@style/myMaterialButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pay_deail_submit_btn"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is some style info:

```
<style name="myMaterialButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Here are colors:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">@color/silver</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#2A2E43</color>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Material Official Source](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#outlined-button) you should use `app:backgroundTint` in your style

meanwhile for checking "Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" styles you should check buttons on Device or Emulator, sometimes buttons with this style dosent show good in IDE

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md#container-attributes-1), you can use the **`backgroundTint`** attribute:

```
<style name="myMaterialButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <!-- Background color --> 
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

Don't use the `android:background` attribute to change the background color.

Answer (score 1):

`MaterialButton` is visually different from `Button` and `AppCompatButton`. One of the main differences is that AppCompatButton has a 4dp inset on the left and right sides, whereas MaterialButton does not.

You can use `app:backgroundTint` to change the color

With this you need to use

```
android:insetTop="0dp"
android:insetBottom="0dp"
```